# PSU charging / USB charging with data transmission - LiPo cell

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, charging, lipo, usb-device

I am designing Rev.2 of my Geiger counter trying to squeeze in more functionality in it and make it portable.

I decided to go with single LiPo cell 3.7V, STM32 microcontroller and step-up converter 5V with regulation to +3.3V. I wanted also some leeway in future expansion of project regarding communication and connectivity so I added USBMicro connector with CP2102.

As I would need to charge battery I designed this section to acquire power from both USB connector and external PSU rated for +5V. I wanted to power up device when charging as well. There are 3 states this section can be:

1. Ext. PSU connected, USB VBUS disconnected, battery charging, Device powered up

In this state VIN is a positive rail +5V, hence IC12 (P-MOSFET) is open disconnecting V_USB. IC11 is getting 5V and charges Battery through pins 9 & 10 of IC11. Q2 is closed, max. current allowed is 1000mA. VDD is +5V as well since IC13 (P-MOSFET)  is open disconnecting battery during charge. Step-up converter IC9 is disabled since Q1 is closed and pulling EN pin down to GND. +5V is flowing through L3 to +3.3V regulator. Device is powered up.

2. Ext. PSU disconnected, USB VBUS connected, battery charging, Device powered up

In this state VIN is disconnected, hence IC12 (P-MOSFET) is closed allowing current from V_USB to flow. IC11 is getting 5V and charges Battery through pins 9 & 10 of IC11. Q2 is open, max. current allowed is 500mA. VDD is +5V, since IC13 (P-MOSFET)  is open disconnecting battery during charge. Step-up converter IC9 is disabled as Q1 is closed and pulling EN pin down to GND again. +5V is flowing through L3 to +3.3V regulator. Device is powered up.

3. Ext. PSU disconnected, USB VBUS disconnected, battery connected, Device powered up

In this state VIN and V_USB is disconnected. IC11 is not charging up and IC13 (P-MOSFET) is closed due to  lack of voltage on gate. Battery is connected to VDD supplying 3.7V to IC9 step-up regulator with Q1 open and EN pin pulled up to VDD. Once again +5V is flowing to +3.3V regulator. Device is powered up.

As this is first try of mine when powering device from battery that you can charge I am quite careful. There are many thing to consider with lithium batteries, specially ones you hold in you hands.

My questions are:

1. Is this a good solution to implement for conditions described above (3 states)?
2. Is it safe? OVP and OCP are on cells' PCB itself
3. Will I be able to communicate with MCU through USB when charging?

Answering in advance - yes I checked here for similar questions and I read few application notes (including AN1149 and AN0046 I found here). Any suggestions regarding schematic and layout are welcomed as I am still learning.

[image: PWR schematic]
[image: PWR layout]
[image: USB schematic]
[image: USB layout]

Comment: Which STM32? If it is a model with USB built-in, the CP2102 is not very useful.

Comment: Hi Justme,
It is STM32F030R8T6 and I'm using Nucleo-64 for prototyping. I was thinking between CP2102 and CP2112 (UART or I2C effectively) and for now I went with former.

Comment: Is it really so cheap that it's not worth to swap the CP21xx and MCU to an STM32 MCU with internal USB? It would use less area due to omitting one chip and the caps and resistors it needs. It would simplify the USB port to be under MCU control, even allow firmware updates directly via USB using DFU. MCU would also be able to request/determine charging current level and use faster/slower charging depending on what kind of USB port is connected (PC, USB charger, etc).

Comment: Yes Justme, is it exactly as you said - it would be easier and space efficient to use for example STM32F767xx MCU with integrated USB communication controller. There are some argument for not doing it. First, I already have some STM32F030R8T6 at hand. I would need to source different MCU later. Secondly I have Nucleo-64 for prototyping and software development. Thirdly it's a personal project (treat it as portfolio) for myself. Lastly, there will be times I can't use solution pointed by you - it's more of educational project for me to gain more in depth knowledge. Maybe in Rev. 3? :)